# Table makes the page horizontally scrollable

Tags: html, css, overflow

Go [here](https://www.dsabyte.com/posts/blog/Solving-a-basic-number-theory-problem/617e8e6194185266a76cc629) and open the page in the mobile view.

### Example image

[image: scrollable]

You can see from the above image `table` is completely inside the parent element but the page is scrollable.

If I remove the `table` by `display:none` then it works fine.

I am not able to get the issue, that is why this is coming out. I have set `overflow: auto` on the table.

Comment: [Something in my website doesn’t work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) It would be a better question if you copied over the relevant code.

Comment: @sallf the code is not written by my, I am using markdown parser and viewer library. So, it's not possible for me to paste the code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `<body>` tag. I have tried it on the element inspection and worked fine.

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden` on body tag is not good, because this way other content becomes hidden.